# How can I mention a user with discord.py and display a random message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a command that picks a random message from `keyList` and tells the mentioned user to say it. When I run the command, I don't get any output, and nothing happens.

```
keyList = ['q','w','e','r','t','y']
 
@client.command()
async def giveCommand(ctx, member : discord.Member):
  print('giving command')
  key = keyList[random.randint(0, len(keyList))]
  await ctx.send(f"{member} You have 24 hours to say " + key)
```

Please let me know if you know what the problem is.

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: @Nurqm No, there is no error.

Comment: Do you have an `on_command_error` event?

Comment: @Nurqm Yes, but that does not give output either.

Comment: @Ben I write `!giveCommand <mentioned user>` in a server that the bot is in to call it.

Comment: Remove that event, restart your bot, execute the command again and check for errors.

Comment: It works for me

Answer (score 0):

In order to mention a user, you have to get `User.mention`, which is a special string that tells discord that you are trying to mention a user. This should fix the problem:

```
keyList = ['q','w','e','r','t','y']
 
@client.command()
async def giveCommand(ctx, member : discord.Member):
  print('giving command')
  key = keyList[random.randint(0, len(keyList))]
  await ctx.send(member.mention + ", You have 24 hours to say " + key)
```